# Symfony call a config

Tags: symfony

I try to call a config from config_dev.yml, config_preprod.yml ... in doctrine configuration.

I have for example :

```
doctrine:
   dbal:
      connexions:
         test:
            driver : ...
            host: 1.1.1.1
            port: 1111
            ...
```

And in an controller i have for now :

```
$output = file_get_contents('http://1.1.1.1:1111/...', 0, $var)
```

And i would like replace the http:... by my config doctrine.dbal.connexions.test, its possible ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get read the configuration with

```
$this->getParameter('doctrine.dbal.connexions.test');
```

https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/parameters.html